# Is it possible to work with flowtype and async await transforms together?

Tags: javascript, async-await, flowtype

I. I want to use Facebook `flow` type checker, and I would like to use Babel `async/await` transformer. Ther are working together?

I afraid, that the syntax checker of flow, will not understand the syntax of the code.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

It is not written in the documentation, but by reading the issues and source-code of `FlowType` I found that `Async/await support added in v0.12`.

### More info:

- [The relevant issue source](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8)
- [Some trails in the source code for await](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=await&type=Code)

Comment: What does the second link refer to?